# Looking for a quote which is like "it's not for their sins, it's ours"

Tags: quotes

I came across this quote some years back and I don't remember it correctly. If I understood it correctly it implied that when some things go wrong (especially relationships) it's not the other person's fault, it's ours that we let go that relationship. I am not sure about the meaning but it was close.

It has 'sins' in the quote.

Can you help me find the quote? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this related to Easter? You might find something relevant in this list of quotations: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sin

Answer (score 1):

**"It's not you, it's me."**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_not_you,_it%27s_me):

> **It's not you, it's me** is a popular phrase used in the context of breaking up, and is intended to ease the dumpee's feeling in the knowledge that it wasn't their fault, but rather the fault of the dumper.

However, it's become something of a cliche, which is often taken to mean the *opposite* of it's original intended purpose.

The quoted article continues:

> Merriam-Webster described it as a "much-reviled, often-used excuse." The Huffington Post described it as "overworked and cliched." Psychology Today argues that "opening with 'It's not you, it's me' is just going put your partner on the defensive from the start.

Comment: I appreciate it. It is pretty similar to this but it has 'sins' in the quote.

Comment: @technazi I'm afraid I know of no idiom involving both sins and ending a relationship.

Comment: @JasonBassford It's called 'infidelity'!